# iterate json logins in python

Tags: python, json, loops, variables

i am attempting to automate logging in with python. the logins are stored in a json file for easier administrating those values without touching the python file.

my json file looks like this

```
{
 "carl":
    {"name": "carlcarlson", "pw": "lenny"},
"lenny":
    {"name": "lennylennards", "pw":"crrrl"}
}
```

my python script imports the json file as such:

```
import json
import pprint

with open('logins.json') as logins_json:
looog = json.load(logins_json)
```

command `pprint(looog)` results to

```
{u'carl': {u'name': u'carlcarlson', u'pw': u'lenny'},
u'lenny': {u'name': u'lennylennards', u'pw': u'crrrl'}
```

however, i cannot seem to figure out how to iterate through this file; how do i print (or rather, set as variables) each persons name and password?

i realize replacing "carl" and "lenny" in my json file with "1" and "2" would be an option; for easier editing the json file i would rather stick to "readable" names as identifiers.

thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: It's a dictionary. Do you know how to work with dictionaries?

Comment: Note that Lenny's surname is Leonard, not Lennards :)

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's strings or numbers makes no difference at all. This is a dict, which in turn contains other dicts. To can get the values of the outer dict directly with `looog.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just dealing with a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

```
looog = {u'carl': {u'name': u'carlcarlson', u'pw': u'lenny'}, u'lenny': {u'name': u'lennylennards', u'pw': u'crrrl'}}

for user,details in looog.items():
    print(user)
    print(details['name'])
    print(details['pw'])
```